# why the value of 'total paid' field on a completed order gets doubled?

Tags: commerce

I am using commerce 2 on Drupal 8. I need to get the value of a customer has paid on a completed order. But strangely the 'total paid' value gets doubled, here is output of dsm($order):

```
[total_price] => Array( [x-default] => Array
                     ([0] => Array(
                            [number] => 10.000000
                            [currency_code] => CAD)))

[total_paid] => Array([x-default] => Array
                        ([0] => Array(
                            [number] => 19.99
                            [currency_code] => CAD)))
```

The correct value should be 10.00 like 'total price', the 'total paid' should be the same. My purpose is to get the money value a customer has paid on order so I can update the value of another custom field. Isn't the 'total paid' field is the one I am looking for?

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant: I have multiple currencies enabled on the site and set up example (On-site) in test mode as the payment gateway to test orders.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the payment gateway you're using is creating a payment for the incorrect amount. I'd start there

Comment: thanks Leigh. When I checked the orders as the admin (admin/commerce/orders), there are two payments: one payment is CA$9.99, the 2nd is CA$10.00. The 2nd is the product ordered, I guess that is why the value for 'total paid' is $19.99. but I really don't know why the first payment is added since I only ordered one product with a price of $10. I verified the payment gateway and didn't see any odd things there, most of them are just default settings.